# How to set Dynamic enable/disable for dynamically added checkox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To generate dynamic check boxes I am using map like this

```
{{range $key, $val := .package.Group_Name_Map}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <label><strong>{{$val}}</strong></label>
    </div>              
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="read">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="write">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="update">
    </div>

  </div>
{{end}}
```

now i want these checkboxes to be predefined by dynamically got values.
This i have done for beego framework

Comment: _predefined by dynamically got values_...can't get it? put lights on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var statement = true;
if (statement) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r0o8kxvo/1/

This will `select` all `input`'s that are `checkboxes` and make them `checked` if the `statement` is `true`

`statement` is a placeholder for what you call

> dynamically got values

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

> In HTML Just add disabled="disabled" as an attribute to disable and checked="checked" as attribute to checked as default

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="update" checked> checked
<input type="checkbox" name="update" disabled> disabled
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"> disable and checked
```

in jQuery use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function

```js
$('.checks').prop("checked",true);
$('.checks1').prop("disabled",true);
$('.enable').prop("disabled",false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks" name="update"> checks1
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks1" name="updates"> disabled
    <input type="checkbox" class="enable" name="updates"> enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

> 1.Dynamically create checkbox

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var cb1 = "<input type='checkbox' class='cb1' value='cb1'>I am a checkbox.";
    $("#panel").html(cb1);
});
```

> 2.Dynamically enable/disable checkbox

```
$('#ble').click(function () {
    var stat = $(".cb1").is(":disabled");
    if (stat) {
        $(".cb1").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(".cb1").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

> 3.Dynamically check/uncheck the checkbox

```
$('#check').click(function () {
    var stat = $(".cb1").is(":checked");
    if (stat) {
        $(".cb1").prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(".cb1").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/next2u/wsx4ysje/)